# WPF How to move application to first at standby screen?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winapi, window

I'm making a taskbar application by wpf on window.
When user shutdown, the application will be shown on standby screen with a message by using [ShutdownBlockReasonCreate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-shutdownblockreasoncreate)

If I open many programs, the application sometimes will move to bottom on standby screen like this

[image]

How can I move it to the top on this screen?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to control the order of this list programmatically.

Even if it was possible, you would have to ask yourself, [what if two programs did this?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413)